# Don't know how to get index from button list C# winForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a program code for creating graphs from graph theory.

Clicking on a grid generates a graph node with the corresponding index. Buttons are generated on the right. I want the nodes to be connected by an edge when the button is clicked. For example, when you click on the button on line 1 and column 2, an edge will be drawn connecting circles 1 and 2.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4wk6.png)

Button generation code

```
List<Button> btnList = new List<Button>();
for (int z = 1; z <= count; z++)
                {
                    for (int x = 1; x <= count; x++)
                    {
                        Button btn = new Button();
                        btn.Text = 0.ToString();
                        btn.Location = new Point(z*30, x*30);
                        btn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
                        btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                        btn.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(btnClick);
                        panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
                        btnList.Add(btn);
                    }
                }
```

The code of the event describing the click of the button

```
public void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            button.Text = (int.Parse(button.Text)+1).ToString();

            

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            //g.DrawLine(pen, );
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        }
```

Maybe the question is very stupid, but I do not understand how to refer to the indexes of the pressed button in the btnClick function.

Comment: every control has a Tag property that you can set to anything you want

Comment: I can try using the key. I also thought, maybe create an inheritor of the button class, in which to add a property with indexes

Comment: I didn't find such a property.

Comment: Visual studio prompts only properties KeyDown, KeyPress, KeyPress

Comment: Property tag will solve my problem

Comment: @KonstantinRatnikov My apologies, I meant Tag, not Key, so: a Control (from which Button is derived) has a Tag property, which is an Object that you could assign something to, if that is what you're asking for. The Object could be an instance of a Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have, for every object in C#, a Tag property which is free. You can use it to store the coordinates of your button.

So, insert before you add the btn to the panel1.Controls, something like:

```
btn.Tag = new Point(z, x);
```

Then, in the btnClick delegate, to get back your coordinates, you use something like:

```
Button button = sender as Button;
Point p = button.Tag;
int z = p.X;
int x = p.Y;
```

You can keep the Button button = (Button)sender; The only difference is that casting can throw an exception but the keyword 'as' can't.

As I am writing this, I see the new comments and your reply. Tag isn't in the delegates like KeyDown but with the properties like Location, Size, Text, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was possible

Comment: You're very welcome, @KonstantinRatnikov. The Tag trick can be useful in other places, and you'll note that Caius' answer is more 'ecologic'!

Answer (score 0):

You already store z and x:

```
btn.Location = new Point(z*30, x*30);
```

You can do this in the click handler to retrieve them:

```
int z = button.Location.X / 30;
int x = button.Location.Y / 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers.

I add code when generation buttons

```
btn.Tag = new Point(z, x);
```

and i use btn.Tag when click on button

```
Point p = (Point)button.Tag;
            int z = p.X;
            int x = p.Y;
```